# Sass for just HTML

Tags: html, sass

I found SASS and sounds great that you can use variables, make code cleaner, etc... 
But, I see it's for Ruby on Rails.

Is there a way to make it work just with HTML as if it was CSS?
If it's not possible is there something similar out there?

Thanks!

(btw I'll be using php)

Comment: I'm using sass (& compass) with an ocaml project to generate my css and sprites. You should be good.

Comment: You can use Sass anywhere. I use it with django, php, hyde, rstblog, static html, you name it. You need ruby installed on your dev machine, but you certainly don't need to be working on RoR projects. It's the most robust of the pre-processors, and I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use SASS anywhere, providing that you've got ruby installed. It doesn't have to be a Ruby on Rails project, you just need to install the SASS gem.

See - http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html

Alternatively there are other CSS pre-processors such as LESS and Stylus that are compiled using node.js rather than ruby.

**LESS** - http://lesscss.org/

**Stylus** - http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/

They each provide similar functionality, but with slightly varying syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Jade is the name of the preprocessor you're looking for.

[Css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/111-get-yourself-preprocessing-in-just-a-few-minutes/) mentions and shows it in that video tutorial of code kit.
edit: see comments :)

Comment: I mean.. for css not html! :) thanks though that'll be usefull too

Comment: I don't understand? Sass is a preprocessor for CSS... LESS is another option though.

Comment: So I don't need ruby? cause it says install using gem etc.. I need it just for my html document, I want sass to work as if it was normal CSS :D

Comment: Well you just need Ruby on your PC/Mac (mac has ruby by default, and it's very easy to setup on PC) to turn it into a normal CSS file, you can then just upload that plain CSS file to your host. Or in other words, you don't need to touch Ruby or anything on your server that you wouldn't normally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sass with anything actually, using the sass binary. The following will watch the folder ./css/sass for changes and place compiled .css files in ./css

```
sass --watch css/sass:css
```

Answer (score 2):

Haml and Sass have been used in Ruby for sometime to simplify templates (Haml) and make CSS more intelligent, flexible and manageable (Sass); now they come to PHP in [phaml](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/).

1. Framework independent. PHamlP can be used with any framework
   (wrapper functions are required to integrate with frameworks; an
   example for Yii is provided - I'd welcome contributions for other
   frameworks) or standalone.
2. Indentation auto-detect. PHamlP allows use of spaces or tab as the
   indentation character and automatically detects which on a per file
   basis; and, if spaces, how many.
3. Rendering options to support readability for development and
   minimised whitespace for production.
4. Haml & Sass V3.x compliant (.sass and .scss SASS syntax support,
   FireSass integration, new variable syntax, @extend directive)
5. Includes Compass (PHamlP V3.2 and greater).